# Running Remote Bash Script that Contains nohup Command

Tags: bash, networking, ssh, nohup, sshpass

I am trying to remotely run a script on an Ubuntu server that contains the line:

```
nohup /mypath/mybashscript.sh &
```

I am using this command from my remote system

```
nohup sshpass -p "password" ssh -t -t user:password@host /mypath/mybashscript.sh
```

However this is NOT working. nohup.out contains:

```
successful command 1
successful command 2

STARTING: nohup /home/ark/epicsrvrmgr/ark/start.sh &
Connection to 73.181.247.193 closed.
```

I'm not sure how to keep the command on the remote host running... (NOTE I'm starting a video game server with the nohup command.)

Comment: Best solution would be to use a Mux like `screen`/`tmux`, but as a poor man's solution you could try using `disown`: `ssh remote '/path/to/script.sh & disown'`

Comment: Did you verify that `/mypath/mybashscript.sh` wasn't running by logging into the remote server and verifying?  What makes you think that remote `nohup` didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up solving my problem by using tmux:

```
#!/bin/bash
tmux new-session -d -s myuser 'echo mypassword | sudo -S mydesiredcommand'
```